# Excessive memory usage with C# client in CouchbaseNetClient 2.0.3.1

Tags: c#, memory, couchbase

I am using CouchbaseNetClient 2.0.3.1 for a C# client and ran into out of memory situations when I started threading my application.  While I have not tried to identify every suspect situation, I have created a simple scenario that demonstrates what I consider to be excessive memory usage.

My Couchbase server has a completely empty bucket.  From my C# client, I open a bucket and am surprised to see that my application's memory usage is over 340 MB at this point.  Now that the bucket is opened, I attempt to delete 10 invalid items from the database.  The memory usage stays the same.  I then start running the removal of items concurrently and start to see an increase in memory usage and see that it finally levels off around 1 GB.

I am concerned by the high memory usage all around, but processing concurrently does not seem like an option with what I am seeing.  Is there something I can do to prevent such high memory usage, or is this an issue that will get addressed?

```
class Program
{
    static void PrintMemoryUsage(string label)
    {
        var mb = 1024 * 1024;
        var gc = GC.GetTotalMemory(true) / mb;
        var pm = Process.GetCurrentProcess().PagedMemorySize64 / mb;
        Console.WriteLine($"{label}:  GC={gc} MB  PM={pm} MB");
    }

    static void ExampleOfThreadedMemoryIssue()
    {
        var cluster = new Couchbase.Cluster();
        var poolConfig = cluster.Configuration.PoolConfiguration;
        poolConfig.MaxSize = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        poolConfig.BufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
        PrintMemoryUsage("Created a cluster");

        var bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("default");
        PrintMemoryUsage("Opened a bucket");

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            bucket.Remove("CompletelyInvalidKey");
        }
        PrintMemoryUsage("Removed 10 items serially");

        for (int concurrent = 1; concurrent <= 10; ++concurrent)
        {
            var tasks = new List<Task>();
            for (int i = 0; i < concurrent; ++i)
            {
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
                {
                    bucket.Remove("CompletelyInvalidKey");
                }));
            }
            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
            PrintMemoryUsage($"Removed {concurrent} items concurrently");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress any key to continue.");
        Console.ReadKey(false);
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExampleOfThreadedMemoryIssue();
    }
}
```

Here are the results of running this example on my machine:

```
Created a cluster:  GC=0 MB  PM=18 MB
Opened a bucket:  GC=321 MB  PM=346 MB
Removed 10 items serially:  GC=321 MB  PM=346 MB
Removed 1 items concurrently:  GC=321 MB  PM=346 MB
Removed 2 items concurrently:  GC=481 MB  PM=508 MB
Removed 3 items concurrently:  GC=641 MB  PM=668 MB
Removed 4 items concurrently:  GC=801 MB  PM=829 MB
Removed 5 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=991 MB
Removed 6 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=991 MB
Removed 7 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=990 MB
Removed 8 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=990 MB
Removed 9 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=990 MB
Removed 10 items concurrently:  GC=961 MB  PM=990 MB

Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: perhaps it's because `Task.WaitAll` waits for all processes to complete and some processes that are running make take longer than others this is all I can think of off the top of my head.. but I am shooting in the dark just at first glance... [Task.WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Use a memory profiler.

Answer (score 0):

The excessive memory usage is because of the size of the buffer pool you have configured: 1024 * 1024 * 20 (times the MaxSize)

```
 poolConfig.BufferSize = 1024 * 1024 * 20;
```

The default is 1024*16, any reason for increasing this? The largest document size supported by Couchbase Server is 20MB.